# Creating custom tasks in Biztalk scheduled task adapter

Tags: c#, adapter, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I need to run my Biztalk orchestration for every two hours and trigger will be a file that is present in location say "Folder2"

So I used folders "Folder1" and "Folder2". I copy files from "Folder1" to "Folder2" on timely basis(say for every two hours).I acheived this by writing some C# code and giving exe of this console application as Task in windows scheduler.

"Folder2" is configured as receive location in BizTalk application. So as soon as files are moved to "Folder2" they trigger BizTalk orchestration

Now I want to try with BizTalk scheduled task adapter.I can not use "XmlStringStreamProvider" as I want to strictly use files present in "Folder2".
Is there any possibility to run exe of C# appllication, in Task like in case windows scheduler?

Am completely new to it :-( Any suggestions would be of real help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your specific question could be yes, but I wouldn't take that path.  What you'd have to do is write a custom task that runs the .exe.

The Interface for the Scheduled Task Adapter is pretty simple so I strongly recommend you just implement the functionality directly rather than try to reuse the .exe.

All you have to do really is stream copy the contents of the file in Folder2 into the BizTalk Message submitted by the Task.